# Determine range of possible datetimes for a timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

Given a timestamp string and a format string, I would like to determine the minimum and maximum datetime objects that this timestamp could belong to. For example, for the following inputs, this would look like:

`timestamp='2020', format='%Y'`:

```
[datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)]
```

`timestamp='2020-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d'`:

```
[datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2020, 1, 1, 23, 59, 59)]
```

Another way to frame this question is, given a timestamp and format string, what is the level of precision of the resulting datetime object?

If I use `datetime.strptime()`, it always gives me the default values for missing arguments. One possible solution would be to monkeypatch `datetime` to use the max values instead of min values, but this is pretty hacky. Another solution would be to parse the string for all possible format codes, but this is tedious and error prone since the string can contain literal `%%` characters.

Comment: Parsing the string for format codes is actually terribly _easy_ with a regexp like `%(.)` -- you can then just ignore the match if the capture group is `%` (or anything unknown)...

Comment: In what context do you need this? I get the sense there's a simpler to solution to the actual application of the solution you're asking about (i.e. this might be an XY problem)?

Comment: The context is that I'm building an R-tree for spatiotemporal data, and I need to determine the min and max possible timestamps to use

Comment: The regex approach is a bit more complicated because a string like `%%Y` does not contain the format code `%Y`, it contains the literal `%` character and the letter `Y`. Also, there are a lot of possible format codes to check for, so I need to check for a lot of possible values.

Comment: Are you content with the defaults Python chooses? I.e. should `'Apr'` when parsed with `'%b'` represent the first of April of 1900? (even though the year wasn't mentioned?) That seems odd for the application you mention? (and be interpreted as the first to the 30th of April of 1900, of course?)

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if a month format code is provided, then a year format code is also provided. This means that if we can determine the highest resolution format code provided, we can easily determine the range of values. But I would rather not have to manually parse the format string if possible.

Comment: That's quite the assumption - a date string like `'Wed Apr 9'` would seem like a pretty common occurrence to me, depending on the application. You should probably include some more information in the question on exactly what range of datetime values you expect to encounter.

Comment: Also think about other idiosyncrasies of the datetime parser function. For example, if you provide both a "day of the year" as well as a specific date, it will use the day of the year without error (e.g. `'15, 9 Apr 1975'` with `'%j, %d %b %Y'` is 15 Jan of 1975)

Comment: And another: if you include both `%b` and `%m` whichever is later in the format string takes precedence - exploring the weirdness of that function is fun, but your question is unanswerable unless you're very clear about the restrictions and required behaviour.

Comment: Yes, these are all valid points. In my application, I am working with satellite imagery, so if a year isn't provided, a month would be useless. I think it's safe to assume that conflicting data (julian day that doesn't match month day) doesn't exist. I'm not looking for a provably correct answer that handles all possible input, but a best effort answer that handles reasonable input.